# Why is Angular 16 breaking RouterEvent constructor? (MSAL)

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-ad-msal

I have had MSAL working fine with Angular up until version 16 that was just released.

Currently I am facing the following error:

```js
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:34:34 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<Event_2>>): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(e: RouterEvent) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<Event_2>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: Event_2) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(e: RouterEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Event_2) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'e' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Event_2' is not assignable to type 'RouterEvent'.
          Type 'RouteConfigLoadStart' is missing the following properties from type 'RouterEvent': id, url
  Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: (value: Event_2) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(e: RouterEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Event_2) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'e' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Event_2' is not assignable to type 'RouterEvent'.

34     this.router.events.subscribe((e : RouterEvent) => {
```

I know that in the upgrade notes of Angular 15 -> 16 it lists the following but I am not sure how this is resolved.

```
The Event union no longer contains RouterEvent, which means that if you're using the Event 
type you may have to change the type definition from (e: Event) to (e: Event|RouterEvent)
```

Below is the code that exists in the component.

```js
  constructor(@Inject(MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG) private msalGuardConfig: MsalGuardConfiguration
  ,private router: Router, private broadcastService: MsalBroadcastService, private authService: MsalService) { 
    this.router.events.subscribe((e : RouterEvent) => {
      this.navigationInterceptor(e);
    })
  }
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hav you tried doing what is suggested ? replace `(e : RouterEvent)` with `(e : Event|RouterEvent)` ?

Comment: I have, it did not help.

Comment: can you give a try to what's written in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent) ?

Comment: Did you import the correct resource?
import {Event} from '@angular/router';

Comment: @user68288 did you manage to fix this issue? I am having the same problem

Comment: @Erex -- we ended up staying on 15 for the moment as we could not resolve it.

Comment: Event|RouterEvent do this then pipe filter event instanceof RouterEvent

Answer (score 1):

So eventually, accumulating the stuff mentioned in comments and existing answers, the way that worked for me was following [the official docs' example](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent#description) and adding the `Event` import with further narrowing the event type down if some particular properties (like `url`) are necessary, something like:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((event: Event | RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationEnd) // or RouterEvent, or whatnot
).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
  console.log(event.url)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `Event` from `@angular/router`.

```
import {
  ActivatedRoute,
  NavigationEnd,
  Router,
  RouterEvent,
  Event, // Ensure this is in the list of imports from @angular/router
} from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: But all the properties now are gone from the event. I can only `toString()` it now. How can I get the URL for example now?

Answer (score 0):

`Event|RouterEvent` works fine, but not in all cases because if you reference to the url property (something like `e.url`), it will raise an error that `Property 'url' does not exist on type 'RouteConfigLoadStart'`

Then based on the type definition below, you should know when to use the specific event type for your purpose, eg `e: NavigationStart` or `e: NavigationEnd`

```
declare type Event_2 = NavigationStart | NavigationEnd | NavigationCancel...
export { Event_2 as Event }
```

Example of the code in my project after migrating to Angular 16:

```
this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof RouterEvent)).subscribe((e: NavigationEnd) => {
  if (e.url.startsWith('something')) {
    // do something
  }
});
```